# disable white spaces using inputfilter - android

Tags: android

I am a beginner in android and I would like to disable white spaces in edittext using inputfilter.

How can I do that?

I found this code in the net:

```
InputFilter filter = new InputFilter() {
            public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
                for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {
                    if (!Character.isLetterOrDigit(source.charAt(i))) {
                        return "";
                    }
                }
                return null;
            }
        };
```

but it allows only letters and digits.

Thank you

Comment: What about this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9759600/5778152 ? Is that what you want ?

Comment: @NicolasCortell yes, but I do not know how to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code in a modified version:

```
    InputFilter filter = new InputFilter()     
{  
    @Override  
    public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend)   
    {   
        for (int i = start; i < end; i++)
            if (!Character.isLetter(source.charAt(i)) && !Character.isSpaceChar(source.charAt(i)))
                return "";

        return null;  
    }
};

myTextView.setFilters(new InputFilter[] { filter });
```

Code from SO-Thread [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15966004/4565322)